# Deep Learning with many categories

Tags: classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, many-categories

Do deep learning algorithms run into trouble when tasked with classifying high dimensional input into one of *many* categories? By many I mean thousands or millions. If it does, how could one deal with this problem? Any references?

Comment: by deep learning do you mean neural networks?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yeah, sorry I'm not up to speed on the jargon with these things

Comment: In science, when categorizing with millions of possible categories, usually some hierarchcal system is built, like in biological systematics.  There will be two cases: Building such a system, or cateforizing into a known system. Which case is yours?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks that's helpful. I don't really have one, I am just being curious at the moment. I know the output of say a CNN will give you a vector of probabilities over your categories, so I am curious if and why things become hard to discern when looking at examples besides this MNIST dataset. The more bins you divide up $1$ into, the smaller the differences in their volume. just wondering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If it does, how could one deal with this problem? Any references?

You can use hierarchical softmax, importance sampling, noise
contrastive estimation, or negative sampling: they are commonly used in language modeling, for example.

FYI:

- [Why is hierarchical softmax better for infrequent words, while negative sampling is better for frequent words?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/180076/12359) (The answer gives a brief overview of what hierarchical softmax and negative sampling are)
- http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ section "12.4.3 High-Dimensional Outputs": presents hierarchical softmax, importance sampling, noise contrastive estimation, and negative sampling.
- Dyer, Chris. "Notes on Noise Contrastive Estimation and Negative Sampling." arXiv preprint arXiv:1410.8251 (2014).  https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.8251